# Calendar with weeks starting by Monday / Vanilla JS / without jQuery

Tags: javascript, date, internationalization

I have search for many days how to make a calendar (without plugin/library) with weeks start by Monday, and working for months start by Sunday. Here my solution.

Use this order of days labels:

```
var days_labels = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
```

The trick is when you define the first day of week (0 is Sunday), use this:

```
var first_day = new Date(this.year, this.month, 1),
    first_day_weekday = first_day.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : first_day.getDay();
```

In human language: if `first_day` is a Sunday (0), use 7, else use the initial value.

With this all the loop is correct and works perfectly on every month. Fully example: http://codepen.io/jacknumber/pen/RWLyQW

**There is no question, its for user search help on this issue**
Thanks

(feel free to correct my english :))

Comment: Self-answering a question is fine, but you need to actually *post both a question and an answer* (which you'll be able to accept after some time). This way other people can chime in with their answers as well, and who knows... maybe someone will come up with an even better answer than you did.

Comment: Too bad `days_labels[first_day_weekday]` will give wrong result, and even fail for Sunday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you need to define with wich week day the month starts. Javascript, like other programing languages, starts its weeks by Sunday. To change the week day order, you can define an array with the new days order. The sunday return zero (*Mon* in the array) so set it at 7 (*Sun* in the array).

Long version:

```
var first_day = new Date(this.year, this.month, 1),
    first_day_weekday;
if (first_day.getDay() == 0) {
    first_day_weekday = 7;
} else {
    first_day_weekday = first_day.getDay();
}
```

Short version:

```
var first_day = new Date(this.year, this.month, 1),
    first_day_weekday = first_day.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : first_day.getDay();
```